# Will my British unlocked iPhone 6 work in the US with Verizon?

Tags: iphone

I have an unlocked iPhone 6 (A1586) that I purchased from Apple here in the UK.   I'd like to know if I'll be able to use it in the US with Verizon.  What will I have to do?

Just buy a Verizon SIM and pop it inside?

Verizon uses CDMA right? do they sell SIM cards too?.  I'd like to use Verizon CDMA there and not any other, as I'll be working for a US group that uses Verizon.   I know that my iPhone 6 is CDMA capable (that's what I can see in support.apple.com/specs for my iPhone model).

Please don't advise on any GSM networks, Verizon is what I need.

Comment: My phone purchased in Switzerland, unlocked worked fine in the UK with a UK sim if that helps.

Comment: Verizon is probably the worst carrier to work with in terms of activating phones that they didn't originally sell as official Verizon models, so this is going to come with a giant "your mileage may vary" caveat, but theoretically if you go to a Verizon store, you should be able to do a SIM-only activation and put the SIM into your iPhone 6 and have it work. Theoretically.

Comment: That said, when using a SIM card on Verizon, you are not actually using their CDMA network but rather their 4G LTE network.